# Nuances of type theory of Isabelle Proof Assistant

Tags: isabelle, isar

I've read this paper
http://www21.in.tum.de/~berghofe/papers/TYPES2002_slides.pdf .

It contains calculus for Isabelle type system on page 7. In this calculus "term has type" and "proof has term".

1) **Does exist more detailed paper on this calculus?**

2) The only two rules which I do not understand are those which relate to constants.

2.1) **What does "c_{[\vec{\tau}_n / \vec{\alpha}_n]}" mean?** It is a proofs which are constants. We have, for example, constant "impI" on page 9. How these tau and alpha relate to "term of impI".

2.2) **Could you please clarify the rule  $\Sigma(c) [\vec{\tau}_n / \vec{\alpha}_n] $.** ?
At first glance it may be translated as  "any set of terms which depend on proof(!) constant with any amount of types instead of atomic types", but I don't see any sense in it.

3)I am also interested in **papers on semantics of this calculus and/or correctness theorem of it**.

I appreciate any related information. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to discuss nuances of research presentations for 15 years ago.
Anyway, the corresponding paper is here: http://www21.in.tum.de/~berghofe/papers/TYPES2002.pdf . It may contain some further explanations.